# Accurate "Last Modified" timestamp in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I've been trying to find a simple way to add a "last modified" timestamp in Google Sheets. I found [this article](https://aryanirani123.medium.com/add-last-modified-timestamps-to-google-sheets-7671f70529fb) that was working very well for me, exactly as simple as I needed. However, I noticed that when I open the sheet again after about a day, all timestamps will update to the open-time instead of the last time I actually modified the cell range.

Many of the other answers to questions similar to mine are too complicated for what I need, and I haven't been successful in editing them to be simpler.

I am inexperienced in Apps Script and could not find a good place to do research on it's documentation unfortunately.

Comment: [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that now by using the "data extraction" function:

1. Create a new document
2. Put the URL of the google sheet in a cell
3. Convert it to a chip
4. Use the data extraction method and choose "Last Modified Time" (e.g. "=A2.[last modified time]")

Here is an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DAnC0TCgoPZ3GPFxAOoFVDRegNFVTFMyzGw2NmI-UXY/

---

Only available to Google Workspace `Business Standard`, `Business Plus`, `Enterprise Essentials`, `Enterprise Standard`, `Enterprise Plus`, `Education Fundamentals`, `Education Plus`, `Education Standard`, and the `Teaching` and `Learning Upgrade` users.
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13524011?hl=en#zippy=%2Cfile-smart-chip

Comment: I can't reproduce the step #4. There are only 3 available options: url, [mime type] and [file name]. If I type [last modified time] directly, then it does not work. Why?

Comment: @АлександрЕрмолин you have to have Google Workspace - does not work on a free account

Answer (score 0):

This stores the last updated data in PropertiesService Document Properties

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  let pupd = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty("pupd");
  let name = sh.getName()
  if (pupd) {
    let upd = JSON.parse(pupd);
    if (upd.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      //e.source.toast("gate1");
      upd[name] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    } else {
      //e.source.toast('gate2');
      upd.pa.push(name);
      upd[name] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    }
    PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty("pupd", JSON.stringify(upd));
  } else {
    //e.source.toast('gate3');
    let upd = { pa: [] };
    upd[name] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    upd.pa.push(name);
    PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty("pupd", JSON.stringify(upd));
  }
}
```

Displays document propert pupd

```
function dispDocProps() {
  let p = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty("pupd");
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<textarea cols="50",rows="12">${p}</textarea>`),"Doc Property pupd")
  Logger.log(p);
}
```

Resets document property pupd to null

```
function resetPupd() {
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty("pupd", '');
}
```

Slightly Enhanced Display of Updates

```
function enhancedDispOfPupd() {
  const obj = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty("pupd"));
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let s = `Past Updates \n`;
  obj.pa.forEach(p => {
    s += `${p} - ${obj[p]}\n`
  });
  ui.showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<textarea cols="40" rows="10">${s}</textarea>`),"Document Property pupd");
}
```

[image]